# Module elasticsearch not found within Angular2 (AngularCLI)

Tags: angular, elasticsearch, angular-cli

I try to use the [Elasticsearch NPM Module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch) in my Angular2 App.

I import it within my service using:

```js
import { Client, SearchResponse } from 'elasticsearch';
```

Typescript Compiler does not complain, but `ng serve` outputs:

```
Cannot find module 'elasticsearch'
```

Same happens if I try to use:

```js
import { Client, SearchResponse } from '../../node_modules/elasticsearch/webpack_config/angular.js';
```

Comment: Did you install the module or did you just download an existing  project?

Comment: I just created a new project using `ng create`, added `"elasticsearch": "^12.1.3",` to package.json and ran `npm install`. Actually that also shall be all necessary to reproduce my problem.

Comment: You can't do that

Comment: @Milad Okay, but why?

Comment: @nik , just kidding, of course you can , you just need to instal the typings : D

Comment: ok, remove what you've added to your package.json, then execute ´npm install elasticsearch --save´. You dont need to add manually entries to your package.json

Comment: @nik , did it work ?

Comment: @Milad Trying, having problems with `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY´-Error, therefore reinstall all.

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca: Do that normally as well, but did not work because of   `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY`-Problem.

Comment: @nik , that's fine, that's just a warning , it should work nontheleess

Comment: @nik , what's the UNMET dependency anyway ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

install the typings for it :

```
npm i @types/elasticsearch@0.0.7
```

Also , have a look at your tsconfig.json and make sure it's in there as well :

Older version of typescript :

```
   "types": [    
      "elasticsearch"
    ]
```

New version of typescript  ( >2)

```
"typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
```

Comment: Okay, i needed to first run `npm i @types/elasticsearch@0.0.7` before installing the other modules, but then it worked.

Comment: I switched my project from the ng2 quickstart seed to the angular-cli skeleton and went from system.js to webpack in the process. I take it that for system.js users this issue can be resolved in the system.js config file? I basically stumbled upon this after having given up on using elasticsearch in my project for the time being because of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall all the packages of elastic search if already done so... using commands like..

```
npm uninstall elasticsearch
npm uninstall -g elasticsearch
npm uninstall -g --save-dev elasticsearch
npm uninstall @types/elasticsearch
```

Now using the angular-cli install the type definitions for elastic search package on your project

```
npm install @types/elasticsearch
```

Now install the elastic search package

```
npm install elasticsearch
```